Why do objects with more mass fall at a faster rate (factoring in air resistance)?
My class had to do an online simulation about the different free fall times of objects, both on Earth and in a vacuum. In it, I noticed that in an atmosphere, objects with greater mass fell faster than objects with less mass. I thought all objects fell at the same rate, and since the shape of the objects was similar, the air resistance likely was as well. Does anyone have an explanation?

Was the size and shape the same for these objects of different mass?

Does this answer your question? If two objects have the same drag coefficient, but one is much heavier, would it fall faster?

because gravity is not a force, but air resistance is, and since the counteracceleration equals force divided by mass, if the mass is higher the counteracceleration is smaller.

When falling, the force on an object is its weight $mg$ (mass $m$, gravitational acceleration $g$) and air resistance $F_\mathrm{drag}$, if any. The former acts downward, and the latter, a function of the object's shape, acts upward—so the downward force $F=mg-F_\mathrm{drag}$.
From Newton's Second Law, an object's acceleration is $a = F/m$.
So the downward acceleration is $a=g-\frac{F_\mathrm{drag}}{m}$. For identical shapes (resulting in identical drag behavior), this is clearly larger for heavier objects—unless air resistance is absent.

Thanks for the help!

I'm curious though: Why do we divide air resistance by mass? Sorry if the questions are a bit simple, I'm in middle school.

I plugged $F=mg-F_\mathrm{drag}$ into $a = F/m$ and worked through the algebra. Both $mg$ and $F_\mathrm{drag}$ get divided by $m$, yielding $g-F_\mathrm{drag}/m$.

Oh ok thank you
